# React Native Status Bar transcluent and hidden issue with Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, statusbar

I use the status bar with transcluent and hidden, I find that the previous screen is visible on the current screen, it looks like the current screen is overshadowed by the previous screen.

can anyone tell me please what's wrong ?
I am using React Native latest version
[screenshoot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbnFX.jpg)
can anyone tell me please , How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried removing the status bar and the previous screen not shown up?

Comment: I already removed the status bar and it”s displaying correctly, and if i am using status bar without transcluent or hidden ,there is no problem too. 
So thats issue cause of i am using transcluent or hidden only

Comment: @codeiam07 Have you resolved your issue, having same one here!